# Copy values of an object of one type to an object of another using C# reflection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, setvalue

I have been tasked with writing a routine against an existing database. This database has several tables that have identical structures, but different names (I did not design this, please do not suggest database design change). I am writing this in EF, and the models were created database-first.

The best option I can think of for this situation is to create a class that has the exact same properties, and create a routine that can accept generic types to copy data from the EF model to the generic model.

My models:

```
    // Sample EF database-first created model
    namespace SampleDataModel.Models
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

        public partial class SampleClassFlavorOne
        {
            public int Id {get; set;}
            public string PropertyOne {get; set;}
            public string Property2 {get; set;}
            public DateTime Property3 {get; set;}
        }
    }

    // Sample of generic class I created
    public class GenericSampleClass{
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public string PropertyOne {get; set;}
        public string Property2 {get; set;}
        public DateTime Property3 {get; set;}
    }
```

My routine:

```
        private static void CopyFlavorToGenericList<T1, T2>(List<T1> fromList, List<T2> toList){
        foreach (var t in fromList)
        {
            //(As you can see, I have tried entering the foreach loop a both ways
            //foreach (var p in typeof(T1).GetProperties())

            foreach (var p in typeof(T2).GetProperties())
            {
                if (p != null && p.CanWrite)
                {
                    dynamic newObject = null;
                    p.SetValue((T2)newObject, p.GetValue(t, null), null);
                }
            }

            toList.Add(toObject);
        }
    }
```

Implementing the routine:

```
switch (flavor){
        case "FlavorOne":
            List<SampleClassFlavorOne> _baseFlavor = db.SampleClassFlavorOne.ToList();
            List<GenericSampleClass> _genericFlavor = new List<GenericSampleClass>();

            CopyFlavorToGenericList<SampleClassFlavorOne, GenericSampleClass>(_baseFlavor, _genericFlavor);
            break;
    }
```

No matter what I try, I always get:

> An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Object does not match target type.

I cannot figure out what I am missing.

1. What may I be missing?
2. Am I going about this the wrong way? If so, what is the correct way to do what I want to do given these conditions?

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `GetProperties()` gets an array of `PropertyInfo` objects that apply *to that specific type*. Thus, when you call `GetValue()`, you are trying to get the value from an object of the wrong type.

I.e. `T2`, the type used to get the `PropertyInfo` object, is `GenericSampleClass`, but the type of the object you pass to the `GetValue()` method is `SampleClassFlavorOne`. In your alternative, getting the properties from `T1`, you have the same problem, but with the `SetValue()` method, passing (in theory…but not really, see "Note:" below) an object of type `GenericSampleClass`, when the `PropertyInfo` object came from the `SampleClassFlavorOne` type.

To do this correctly, you need to get the `PropertyInfo` objects from *both* classes, and use them with the objects of the appropriate type. For example:

```
private static void CopyFlavorToGenericList<T1, T2>(List<T1> fromList, List<T2> toList) where T2 : new()
{
    var map = from p1 in typeof(T1).GetProperties()
              join p2 in typeof(T2).GetProperties()
                  on p1.Name equals p2.Name
              select new { From = p1, To = p2 };

    foreach (var t in fromList)
    {
        T2 toObject = new T2();

        foreach (var copyItem in map)
        {
            if (copyItem.To.CanWrite)
            {
                copyItem.To.SetValue(toObject, copyItem.From.GetValue(t));
            }
        }

        toList.Add(toObject);
    }
}
```

Note: you also had an issue with how you were creating the new object. I don't even know what you meant, using `dynamic` like that, but it wouldn't have worked. You were just passing `null` as the value of the destination object, which doesn't do anything useful.

You need to be able to create instances of the destination object as needed, and the way to do that in the generic method is to add the `new()` constraint to the generic type parameter to require the destination type has a parameterless construction, so that you can in fact use the expression `new T2()` to create a new instance of the object.

Comment: Thank you Peter! Especially, thank you for not only providing the code, but also providing an excellent explanation! I completely understand the issue I was having, as well as the resolve. I do have to defend myself a little bit on your note; that was part of a last ditch effort to try out some of the solutions I had seen on this site - I was wondering how that was supposed to work myself. I could not figure out how to make `T2 toObject = new T2();` work, your suggestion of adding `where T2 : new()` was perfect! Thanks again! +1 and answer.

Comment: One more question on the subject: I understand that reflection in itself is a bit of a performance hit. Is the need to creating the variable `map` going to increase this hit on performance? Looking at the solution, I almost want to say that I am using reflection one time (rather than on every object of my fromList), and therefore am actually decreasing this hit. Would I be correct?

Comment: @Matt: Yes, creating the `map` object once is better than doing it for every object in the list. There is still a cost of calling the `GetValue()` and `SetValue()` methods, which is slower than accessing properties directly. Reflection is slow relative to other techniques, but that may or may not be a problem, depending on how often you need to execute this code. If the speed turns out to be an issue, you can improve matters by building a `Expression` objects to access the properties (which can be compiled) and using a dictionary to cache them across calls to the copying method.